# Rewrite rule parameter htaccess from custom CMS to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, seo

I am moving a website from a custom CMS to wordpress and have an issue with some custom rewrite URL that I need to match for SEO purpose.

Original url looks something like this 
/search?Filter=filter1,filtervalue1&Filter=filter1,filtervalue2

filter1 correspond to a WP Taxonomy
filtervalue x correspond to the taxonomy term to search for.

In this original URL, mulitple can be added, so the URL can expand indefinitely, like  Filter=filter1,filtervalue1&Filter=filter1,filtervalue2&Filter=filter4,filtervalue6&Filter=filter8,filtervalue25 etc etc

I need to find a way of Rewriting the url to match the taxonomies in Wordpress, so in some way extract each value of Filter= and then the taxonomies

something like
 /search?filter1=filtervalue1+filtervalue2&filter4=filtervalue6 etc etc

I can't get my head around it and will appreciate some help

thanks in advance

Comment: I know how to work it for 1 parameter, I will do something like `code`RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search?Filter=$1,$2 [QSA]`code` nut how to dynamically pick up the extra ones?

Comment: Or should I use URL parsing to pick up all variable and then do the search locally?